# Modeling Tri-Track with URDF and Simulate it in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to model a Triangular Tracked Wheels robot, which I'm building it physically. (Something similar to Wall-E character). What would be the preferred approach in doing so? I know how to model the sprockets and track's links (I already have the meshes), but how to combine them in one thread and simulate them in Gazebo, is puzzling me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303473/modeling-tri-track-with-urdf-and-simulate-it-in-gazebo/) by [IronFist16](https://answers.ros.org/users/37443/ironfist16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The support for tracked vehicles has been merged to Gazebo 9 and 11. It works only in ODE. You can have a look at the usage here: https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/worlds/tracked_vehicle_simple.world . Non-deformable tri-tracks should be no problem.

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2020-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0